# Arguments not applicable for Java method

Tags: java

My Java web app works fine, however I can see this error alaways showing up in my Eclipse IDE (where this does not show up when using IntelliJ):

> The method bindInterceptor(Matcher>, Matcher, MethodInterceptor...) in the type AbstractModule is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Matcher,
>   Matcher,
>   ShiroMethodInterceptor)   AopModule.java  /web/src/main/java/com/myapp/shiro/aop  line
>   41    Java Problem

What could be a solution for this issue?

**Update:**

[MethodInterceptor.java](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/aop/MethodInterceptor.html)
[ShiroMethodInterceptor.java](https://github.com/cilogi/gaeshiro/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cilogi/shiro/aop/ShiroMethodInterceptor.java)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think it means that you are passing inadmissible parameters. For example you are calling `bindInterceptor` with the parameters `(p1, p2, p3)` where `(p1 instanceof Matcher> && p2 instanceof Matcher && p3 instanceof MethodInterceptor) == false`
I don't know the relashionship between `MethodInterceptor` and `ShiroMethodInterceptor` classes but I suppose for some reason Eclipse suspects their relashionship doesn't allow you to safely pass objects of type `ShiroMethodInterceptor` as `MethodInterceptor`.
Or maybe I just don't get the problem.

Comment: Can you post code for your classes MethodInterceptor and  ShiroMethodInterceptor ?

Comment: @MrD Thanks for the good analysis;

Comment: @Felix the link for the classes is updated in the question

Comment: My guess is that there're more than one class named MethodInterceptor in your project or in the project path settings. Try to explicitly claim the path while trying to pass the parameter (Ex. org.apache.shiro.aop.MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor).